# How do I minimize risk from a contingent job offer?

Tags: job-offer, security-clearance

So I have recently received two job offers from two different companies. Both jobs are cleared positions and are contingent on my ability to obtain that clearance(not an issue). In talking with the recruiters I have been told that it may be the case that the positions may not be available when I am ready to start, but that is not common.

I want to minimize the chance that I will end up with no job, but don't know how companies would react if I accepted both job offers just to make sure I get at least one. How can I minimize the risk that I will end up jobless despite having two good job offers?

Comment: Hey nwonga, and welcome to [workplace.se]! I edited your question a bit to have it match our [help] guidelines a bit better, and get you better quality answers. If you think I changed it too much and that it won't get you helpful answers as written, please feel free to [edit] it as needed. Thanks for the question!

Comment: My first reaction would be to say, enter a contract with one of them that states the conditions and dates for you to be ready to start and you're fine, but if it was that easy, I guess you would just do that. What country are you and the offers in? Is there anything keeping you from entering a contract that starts at a future date where you can be ready?

Comment: My current understanding of how the process works in the US is that a company can not request a security clearance investigation for someone who is not a current employee. Of course, things may have changed in the last couple of years or you may not be in the US (your post and your profile don't indicate your location). Are you sure that you won't have a position (perhaps doing something other than the job that you applied for) while your clearance paperwork is processed after accepting an offer?

Comment: @ThomasOwens is correct. In the US, at minimum, you must have a written offer and acceptance because the company requests the clearance. I also don't think the feds would be happy with two requests for the same person. http://www.clearancejobs.com/security_clearance_faq.pdf

Comment: @nwnoga I see people assuming you are in the US. Are you? Please [edit] your question and add a country tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Executive Summary

The only way to guarantee you will have a job (given that you pass the security clearance) is to get a written offer saying just that. You have three options:

1. Plan A: Fight to get a written offer now
2. Plan B: Refuse to commit to either until a later date
3. Plan C: Tentatively accept both offers

## Plan A

You have two offers right now, from two companies who are interested in you contingent on a security check. Why not talk to each company and say:

> Hey Company A, I know that this job is contingent on security clearance, and that you aren't planning on giving me a written offer until I get that clearance. The thing is that I have already received an offer from Company B as well. If I am going to accept this job, I would need to have an offer in writing saying that I will have the position waiting for me contingent on receiving security clearance.

All of that is true, and if the company is interested in hiring you, there is almost no downside to them giving you an offer saying that they will hire you if you meet the security clearance requirements. Since both companies may assume that you already have a written offer from the other saying the same thing, they will be more willing to at least match it.

At best you get written offers from both companies and get to pick which one you want to actually sign. At worst you get no written offers and have to go to plan B.

## Plan B

Assuming you know when the security clearance will be finished for both jobs, you can tell hold off making a decision until the date both are finished (so you know the results, and can pick which you want based on the results and current situation). You could say something like this:

> I understand that you don't want to commit a written offer until you know the results of the security clearance. I am more than happy to wait until date X to make my decision. If you can't commit to me right now, I want to keep my options open before I commit to your company.

Again, this is all true, and allows you to keep a clear conscience, while keeping both job offers open.

## Plan C

If you are worried that the companies have another candidate waiting to take your role if you ask for too much, or otherwise that they will not take kindly to Plan A or Plan B, you can choose to do something slightly less honest. You can tentatively accept both offers. Because this is not honest, the companies may not take too kindly to you turning down the offer later, but at the end of the day if they wanted to make sure you would join, they could have offered you a contract.

In the best case you only end up with one offer, and just take whichever you get. In the worst case you have to turn one down after having made a verbal agreement that you would take that job. This may cause the employer to blacklist you from future employment, or even possibly to contact the other employer to let them know what you did.

I advocate honesty (Plan A or Plan B), but depending on your situation and judgment you can elect to go with Plan C instead.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to minimize the chance that I will end up with no job, but
>   don't know how companies would react if I accepted both job offers
>   just to make sure I get at least one.

I suspect you *do* know that they would react poorly. Otherwise, you could just tell them both "Hey, I'm accepting your job offer, and I'm also accepting another one at the same time. Good luck".

If a company learns that you have accepted another offer (even if you have already accepted theirs), I would expect them to withdraw their offer immediately, and move on to another candidate. In this case, that could happen with both hiring companies at the same time.

If you accept an offer, the company goes through the process of clearing your background check, and then you withdraw your acceptance, your professional reputation will suffer in the eyes of everyone who knows you did this. That list includes people at the company you turned down, and anyone else who learns of your behavior. This will make people wary of hiring you or recommending you for a position in the future.

Don't be that guy/gal.

> How can I minimize the risk that I will end up jobless despite having
>   two good job offers?

If you had only one offer, and it was contingent upon a background check clearance, you would be in the same position.

Since you now have two offers, try to get the clearances completed as quickly as possible so that you get firm offers. Then accept one. Tell them something like "I'm really excited about joining your company, and I would like to accept your offer, once this background check is cleared and the offer becomes firm." Avoid accepting contingent offers.

If you have a strong preference for one company over the other, push hard to get to a place where you can accept their firm offer quickly. If you have no preference between the two offers, then it's not as important - just accept the one that firms up first.

Answer (score 3):

I am a hiring manager for a DoD contractor.  No contractor with any sense will give you anything other than a contingent offer until they 1) are awarded the work and 2) you have the necessary clearance (or interim clearance).

The bidding and award process can take six months or more.  Often, contractors don't have everybody they need on staff for various contracts/tasks and need contingent offers to bid on work -so they use your acceptance to win the work.  Once they get the work, they may or may not actually use you to do it.

Although I wouldn't particularly like it if I found out you had accepted another contingent offer in addition to mine, I would certainly understand the motivation to do so. Keep in mind that certain contractor communities are pretty small and word often gets around.

If the work has not yet been awarded, ask for a reasonable hiring bonus (3-5k) to be paid if you are hired or the contingent offer is cancelled.  If they refuse, that's a good sign they are truly not sure whether the work will materialize.

Assuming the contractor HAS already been awarded the work (you should ask), they need an accepted contingent offer to request that an active clearance be transferred to the company or to request a clearance (some contracts will let you work with an interim while your clearance is being processed, especially is it's just a Secret clearance and not TS or TS-SCI, etc.)

If you are concerned about stability and job security, keep in mind that even if a contingent offer turns into employment, working for a government contractor is basically temping.  You are hired to work on a specifc contract or task and when it ends, so does your job -unless the contractor has other work available.  Really big contractors like Lockheed and Raytheon, etc. often have enough work available at any given time that you can jump from one contract to the next.  Smaller and niche contractors likely will not have work for you after the current work ends.

Ask about the duration of the contract or task order on which you'll be working (most have a date through which they are funded).  Ask if there are options for follow on work (e.g. three one-year options).  Ask what the company's success rate is for winning follow on work (should be better than 50%).  You can ask whether the company expects to have other work for you after the contract ends, but they they will usually just say "we can't guarantee anything, but we hope so."

Severance packages vary WIDELY so be sure to ask for a copy of the benefits package including severance benefits before you accept a job.

In the DoD services industry, it's usually pretty easy to get another job after you get laid off.  "Contract ended" is a typical reason for leaving a past job and isn't held against candidates, however, commercial employers may not understand this and may consider you to be a "job hopper" or a low performer.  So, be sure you want to stay in the contractor realm before you rack up a bunch of short stay jobs.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace and thank you for this detailed answer.  I hope you'll look around the site for other questions of interest to you (perhaps our [other questions about security clearances](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security-clearance).