# contingent job offer

Tags: work-experience

I just recently signed a contingent job offer, and was told that I basically have a job upon successful completion of certain contingencies. I fixed the only problem that the investigator contacted me about and I only have one thing on my background. Why is it taking so long for them to get back to me? Does that mean that they took the offer back? Im nervous because I want this job.

Comment: Hi Rein Prosperous and welcome to [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)! Unfortunately, the question you asked is very similar to [How do I minimize risk from a contingent job offer?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15493) and is likely to be closed as a [duplicate](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). If that question does not address your specific scenario, please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/18714/edit) your question and explain how your situation is different. I hope to see you around! :D

Answer (score 1):

How long has it been since you completed the contingencies, and the posting of this question? One day? One week? One month? If it's been a few days, they may be busy. They may be waiting for your feedback that the contingencies have been fixed, so that they can re-run a background check (or whatever.)

Contact them, tell them that you've completed the contingencies, check and see if they have all the further information they need. That way, if there's still anything outstanding they can tell you. If they're just busy, they can tell you. Above all...don't jump to conclusions here without some definitive feedback from them. They may be waiting for you to contact them and say "I cleared everything" before running a final definitive background check.